# Reprojecting and Plotting GOES16 Full Disk with Python

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib-basemap, unidata, proj

I'm trying to reproject GOES16 Full Disk SST product to a lambert conformal conical projection over a smaller cover area. The approach below has worked for CONUS products, but has been unsuccessful thus far for downsizing the Full Disk in a different projection. I'm using Basemap and PyProj here, but I am open to using cartopy as well.

Reproducible example:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from siphon.catalog import TDSCatalog
from netCDF4 import Dataset, num2date
import numpy as np
from pyproj import Proj     
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
# Go to the Unidata Thredds Server for the Current Day
nowdate = datetime.utcnow()
cat = TDSCatalog('http://thredds-jumbo.unidata.ucar.edu/thredds/catalog/satellite/goes16/GOES16/Products/SeaSurfaceTemperature/FullDisk/' + \
                  str(nowdate.year) + str("%02d"%nowdate.month) + str("%02d"%nowdate.day) + '/catalog.xml')
# grab sst data
dataset_name = sorted(cat.datasets.keys())[-1]
dataset = cat.datasets[dataset_name]
nc = dataset.remote_access()
sst = nc.variables['SST'][:]
# correct the offsets
sst= sst*nc.variables['SST'].scale_factor + nc.variables['SST'].add_offset

# grab time/data/projection info
add_seconds = nc.variables['t'][0]
DATE = datetime(2000, 1, 1, 12) + timedelta(seconds=int(add_seconds))
sat_h = nc.variables['goes_imager_projection'].perspective_point_height
sat_lon = nc.variables['goes_imager_projection'].longitude_of_projection_origin
sat_sweep = nc.variables['goes_imager_projection'].sweep_angle_axis
X = nc.variables['x'][:] * sat_h
Y = nc.variables['y'][:] * sat_h
XX, YY = np.meshgrid(X, Y)

# Plot on the HRRR domain to test
mH = Basemap(resolution='i', projection='lcc', \
            width=1800*3000, height=1060*3000, \
            lat_1=38.5, lat_2=38.5, \
            lat_0=38.5, lon_0=-97.5)

p = Proj(proj='geos', h=sat_h, lon_0=sat_lon, sweep=sat_sweep)
lons, lats = p(XX, YY, inverse=True)

lats[np.isnan(sst)] = np.nan
lons[np.isnan(sst)] = np.nan
xH, yH = mH(lons, lats)

plt.figure(figsize=[16, 12], dpi=100)
mH.pcolormesh(xH, yH,sst, latlon=True,
              cmap='jet')
mH.drawcoastlines()
mH.drawstates()
mH.drawcountries()
```

[image]

Comment: Brian Blaylock may have a [notebook](https://github.com/blaylockbk/pyBKB_v3/blob/master/BB_GOES/mapping_GOES16_TrueColor.ipynb) you are interested in. He uses Basemap and plots the data with a Lambert projection.

Comment: Note that since I do not see an import of the u2py module, I am not sure if your unidata tag was intended for the Rocket Software UniData database.

Answer (score 0):

I've published a [Jupyter notebook](https://github.com/lanceberc/GOES/blob/master/GOES_GDAL.ipynb) with examples for GOES Full Disk and CONUS images.
The solution uses GDAL to warp the image from the Geosynch projection to Lambert Conformal Conic.

Answer (score 0):

In this [jupyter notebook](https://github.com/joaohenry23/GOES/blob/master/examples/v3.2/G16_IR__SRCYL_plot.ipynb) I show how to regrid the ABI data (BT of Channel 13), in this case I regrid a subregion, but you can use de idea to regrid the full disk. This example is part of [tutorial](https://github.com/joaohenry23/GOES/blob/master/examples/index.ipynb) of the [GOES](https://github.com/joaohenry23/GOES) package that I created. I hope that the example and the GOES package are useful to you.